# Nodeos blocks log folder size requirements

Tags: nodeos

The nodeos daemon stores blockchain replay information in the `../nodeos/data/blocks` folder.

In bitcoin-daemon this folder now is more than 100 GB.

In ethereum-daemon - tens of GB.

How fast will the size of this folder grow in EOS considering blocks are generated every 0.5 secs.

Also is it required to replay ALL blocks from the very beginning to init a new nodeos node?

Answer (score 2):

### Update:

**[This link is a download for](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/blocks-nodeos/blocks.tar.gz)** the first 7m blocks and it's 5.5gb compressed.

---

The max block size is 1mb, so we're at around 9 million blocks.  That makes the maximum possible size around 9TB, but this is likely not the case.  I hope someone else can come up with a more accurate answer.